# Можно ли утверждать что данные полученные путем LEFT или RIGTH JOIN точно будут в INNER JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Есть  SQL  запрос  Для  базы данных MySQL, Там используется  несколько INNER и LEFT  JOIN , Один из INNER  JOIN  нужно заменить  LEFT -ом так как некоторые  данные  не  выводятся, после изменения на LEFT JOIN все работает.

Можно ли полагать  что INNER JOIN часть  LEFT JOIN а то есть  данные  полученные  путем LEFT или RIGTH  JOIN   точно будут  в INNER JOIN  ?

Comment: Визуально это можно увидеть здесь: https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Answer (score 1):

Да, можно. `INNER JOIN` выводит все имеющиеся (совпадающие) данные из двух таблиц, в то время как `LEFT JOIN` выводит данные первой таблицы, которая дополняется данными из второй.